# Error al ejecutar aplicación con java web start usando librerías externas

Tags: java

Tengo que desarrollar una aplicación que utiliza un lector de huellas, para ello uso el skd de digitalpersona, desarrolle la app y en mi pc ejectandola desde netbeans funciona sin problemas, si genero el .jar y lo ejecuto funciona bien también, pero como debe ser web, estoy usando java web start. Ya cree el xml como jnlp y subi todo a un servidor, el .jar, la carpeta lib y el .jnlp, intento ejecutarlo, todo va bien y luego me sale la excepcion:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPDataListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at controlbiometrico.ControlBiometrico.main(ControlBiometrico.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Normalmente desarrollo en PHP y hace mucho que no toco java, pero para el proyecto que estoy trabajando me taca hacerlo, pero esto no se como solucionarlo.

Les dejo la url donde tengo mi proyecto http://develop.smartsystemsgt.com/lectorhuellas/ControlBiometrico.jnlp

Comment: Si puedes comparteme tu proyecto y te indico como compilarlo para que no tengas ese inconveniente.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero como no respondian, segui buscando y logre solucionarlo, el problema es que no lo estaba firmando correctamente, pero encontre un tutorial en youtube de como firmar las aplicaciones y funcionó, gracias.